# DateComponentsFormatter show leading zero

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

I use `DateComponentsFormatter` to format `TimeInterval` in iOS. If I have a result of 1:09 a leading zero should be shown. That the result looks like this: 01:09. Is this possible with `DateComponentsFormatter`.

Here is my example code:

```
let interval: TimeInterval = 4155

let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute]
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
formatter.collapsesLargestUnit = false

formatter.string(from: interval)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to format the interval as time, then the best solution is to use `DateFormatter`:

```
let interval: TimeInterval = 4155
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

print(formatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: interval)))
```

That will always use the same format, always displaying hours.

The `DateComponentFormatter` does not pad with zeros because it is supposed to be used with higher units, e.g. you could get results like "300:24" if your `TimeInterval` is high enough.

Comment: One problem with this solution is that the result isn't localized like `DateComponentsFormatter` would be. For example, you get very different results between the two sets of code for Arabic locales.

Answer (score 11):

use `zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad` for example:

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
                formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
                formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
                formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad

                let outPut = formatter.string(from: TimeInterval(duration)) ?? ""
```

Comment: zeroFormattingBehavior is for units which value is equal to zero